# Add little bottom arrow to my tooltip with CSS

Tags: css

I have finally found a CSS code for a tool tip that worked given that I have quite some attributes already. The only thing I'm lacking now is a little arrow at the bottom like most tooltips have (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_bottom). I have seen solutions but that required a different type of tooltip that didnt work for my existing rules and attributes.

The currrent CSS code is as follows:

```css
.subcategory1a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
}

.subcategory1a::after {
  content: "Tooltip1";
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 2vh;
 left: -2vh;
 width: auto;
 padding: 0.5vh;
 z-index: 100;
 color: #757575;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 border: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
 border-radius: 0.5vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1vh #757575;
}
.subcategory1a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1 !important;

}
```

```html
<br>

<br>

<div class="more_info parentcategory1">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1a">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1b">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1c">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info parentcategory2">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory2a"><span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>
```

Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L1T1.png)

Could anyone please help me in adding it?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: what if you also add a HTML so we can see a complete code

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hi, I have added the HTML code, an example of the arrow, and a screenshot how it currently looks on my site. Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: and how you want the little arrow ? with dotted border also and in the bottom ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes exactly, that would be amazing. But I presume it wont be possible to have the arrow and box look as one object because a dotted line will always visually disconnet them right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the other pseudo element with same **border** and apply a rotation **rotation** then adjust size/position as you want:

```css
.subcategory1a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
}

.subcategory1a::after {
  content: "Tooltip1";
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2vh;
  left: -2vh;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.5vh;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #757575;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1vh #757575;
  bottom:8px;
}

.subcategory1a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
  border-right: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom:2px;
  z-index: 200;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.subcategory1a:hover::after,
.subcategory1a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<br>

<br>

<div class="more_info parentcategory1">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1a">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1b">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1c">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info parentcategory2">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory2a"><span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing! that transform and border bottom and border right makes a whole lot of sense now! Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `:after` *pseudo-element* is already being used for the tooltip message, use the `:before` *pseudo-element* for the tooltip arrow.

To make these tooltips more dynamic and easier to implement in other parts of the application, the `:after` pseudo-element's `content` property value will adjust to set itself to whatever the attribute value (`data-tooltip-title`) has been set to; this will allow freedom to set these tooltips on the fly, e.g:

**Code:**

```
.tooltip::after {
   content: attr(data-tooltip-title);
}
```

`<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-title="what your tooltip will say">tooltip</span>`

**Live**

```css
.page {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dedddd;
}

.page p:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  clear: none !important;
  color: black;
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip-title);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.5vh;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #757575;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1vh #757575;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip::before {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #757575;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  top: -8px;
  width: 0px;
}

.tooltip-center::before {
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltip-start::before,
.tooltip-start::after {
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.tooltip-end::before,
.tooltip-end::after {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltip:hover::after, .tooltip:hover::before {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <p><span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-title="what your tooltip will say">tooltip</span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

The code snippet embedded below demonstrates this with the tooltip arrow placed either at the start, center, or end of the word.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.page {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dedddd;
}

.page p:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  clear: none !important;
  color: black;
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip-title);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.5vh;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #757575;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: dashed 1px #2f2f2f;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1vh #757575;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip::before {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #757575;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  top: -8px;
  width: 0px;
}

.tooltip-center::before {
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltip-start::before,
.tooltip-start::after {
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.tooltip-end::before,
.tooltip-end::after {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltip:hover::after, .tooltip:hover::before {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <p><span class="tooltip tooltip-center" data-tooltip-title="Tooltip Center of Word">Foobar</span></p>
  <p><span class="tooltip tooltip-start" data-tooltip-title="Tooltip Start of Word">Foobar</span></p>
  <p><span class="tooltip tooltip-end" data-tooltip-title="Tooltip End of Word">Foobar</span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that I dont have access to the HTML code, so I can only add content via the CSS.